# video auto play is not working with appendChild

Tags: javascript

I found code to automatically scroll text and images and modified this to apply to video content (See Snippet).

The only problem is that the autoplay doesn't get actioned after:

```
appendChild.
```

I've tried (amongst other things):

```
document.getElementById('video').play();
```

Below is the code in current form. Any tips gratefully received!

```js
(function(){
var top=0;
var par = document.getElementById('par')
var scroll = function() {
  top++;
  if( top>=par.firstElementChild.offsetHeight )
  {
    //first element is out of sight, so move to the end of the list
    top=0;
    par.firstElementChild.style.marginTop='';//reset to -
    par.appendChild(par.firstElementChild);

  }
  else
  {
     par.firstElementChild.style.marginTop='-'+top+'px';
     document.getElementById('video').play();
  }
  setTimeout(scroll, 10)
}
scroll();
})()
```

```html
<div id="par">

 <div class="container">
    <video id="video" width="320" height="240" mute loop autoplay>
   <source src="http://benh.am/new_2/img/finger_scroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video id="video" width="320" height="240" mute loop autoplay>
   <source src="http://benh.am/new_2/img/finger_scroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
     <video id="video" width="320" height="240" mute loop autoplay>
   <source src="http://benh.am/new_2/img/finger_scroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container">
     <video id="video" width="320" height="240" mute loop autoplay>
   <source src="http://benh.am/new_2/img/finger_scroll.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should edit the question to contain the script, it's illegible as a comment.

Comment: You must play when the video element is loaded using for instance the `onload` or `onloadeddata` callback to call `play()`. When you use play directly the element is not fully loaded.